# Development Key Hash too short

Tags: facebook, hash, openssl

I need to generate a development key hash for my facebook app, so I downloaded openssl x64 for windows from (https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads) and used

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

But this generates a 27 character encoding; I need a 28 character one. The paths for my openssl and debug.keystore are correct, but it still does not generate a correct length hash.

Comment: SHA1 only provides 20 bytes of material. Base64 encoding is just stretching it to 28 bytes. Is it possible to use SHA256 and truncate it? That will get you 32 bytes, so there's extra beyond the 28 bytes being asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hash ended with a '=', which I misconstrued as part of the code. With the other 27 characters, that resulted in 28 characters.